# SEndGrid not replacing Dynamics Data

Tags: c#, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

My one template is not replacing dynamics data in the email

My Code is given below

```
public static System.Net.HttpStatusCode SendEmailV2(DynamicsModel dynamicsmodel, string templateId, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("Executing SendEmailV2");
            var SendGridApiCode = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SendGridApiCode", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
            var fromEmail = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("FromEmail", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
            var fromName = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("FromName", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

            var dynamicTemplateData = new DynamicData
            {
                Name = dynamicsmodel.FullName
            };

            string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dynamicTemplateData);

            log.Info("json:" + output);

            EmailAddress from = new EmailAddress(fromEmail, "test name");
            EmailAddress to = new EmailAddress(dynamicsmodel.Email, dynamicsmodel.FullName);
          

            var sendGridClient = new SendGridClient(SendGridApiCode);

            var sendGridMessage = CreateSingleTemplateEmail(from, to, templateId, dynamicTemplateData);

            var response = sendGridClient.SendEmailAsync(sendGridMessage).Result;
            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
            {
                log.Info("Emails Sent from SendGrid");
            }
            else
            {
                log.Info("response.StatusCode:" + response.StatusCode.ToString());
            }
            return response.StatusCode;

        }
```

My JSON which is being passed is given below

```
{"name":"Test User"}
```

This happens to one template only. Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you share what your template is doing with the data? Have you tested the data in the template within the SendGrid design tool?